# How to Remove null values of Key in GraphQL Response JSON Data

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have TypeDef like this

```
type Query {
  userList: userListPayload
}

type userListPayload {
  name: String
  test: String
}
```

Client request is

```
query {
    userList {
        name
        test
    }
}
```

Back-End response has not `test` data. If there is not a value, GraphQL set `test` value as `null`. if `test` is null, I do not want `test` key. My expectation response is below

```
{
   "name": "my name"
}
```

GraphQL response is below

```
{
   "name": "my name",
   "test": null
}
```

Is there any way to remove `null` values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Your query is requesting that the return payload include `test` so you're going to get that variable in your payload.

If you made `test` non-nullable in your type, i.e.:

```
type userListPayload {
  name: String
  test: String!
}
```

Then if `test` is null you won't get anything back at all (not even `name`) because one of the required fields is null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did not find anything too in graphql resources.