# How do I exclude null fields in Apollo graphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have a graphql schema:

```
type Query {
  a: String!
  b: String

}
```

I want `b` to be omitted when null, for performance reasons. It's almost always null.

Tried to get the resolver to return an object without `b`. No such luck, Apollo added it for me.

Tried using `@include` on the client:

```
    b @include(if: b)
```

Got

```
Invariant Violation: Argument for the @include directive must be a variable or a boolean value
```

Edit. Looks like there is nothing I can do on the client. How about on the server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Remove null values of Key in GraphQL Response JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74053065/how-to-remove-null-values-of-key-in-graphql-response-json-data)

Comment: Maybe. There has to be a way though. I mean, I am in full control of the server, there has to be a hook or something. A middleware? The answer doesn't appear to be about the server.

Comment: It would be a violation of the spec.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. Bummer. I am sure I am not the only one who has a ton of almost-always-null fields.

Comment: gzip will help a bit

Comment: Actually, I am the only consumer of my server, I don't terribly care about the spec.